# Função Sql Server - 0 horas de hoje até a hora atual

Tags: c#, sql-server, tsql

Por favor preciso selecionar a quantidade de horas em regressão até as 00:00 horas no Sql Server, sempre do dia atual.
consigo isso através de uma função como 'DATEADD'?

Ex: agora são 15:00 hrs gostaria de pegar a quantidade de horas a partir de 00:00 hrs de hoje até a hora atual Getdate(). O que resultaria é claro como as últimas 15 horas.

espero que tenha me feito entender, desde já agradeço!

Comment: Rodolfo, pelo que entendi o resultado vai ser sempre a hora atual, então acredito que você pode utilizar a função `Datepart(hour, current_timestamp)`

Comment: Mooonstro, muito obrigado... era exatamente isso.